# Lookup value in a row based on keyword

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

I'm trying to lookup a value in a row based on a keyword and return the value. 
**Example:**

```
Column 1                Column 2                Column 3                Result
http://1stexample.com   http://2ndexample.com   http://3rdexample.com   =LOOPUP for "1stexample" should return http://1stexample.com
http://1stexample2.com  http://2ndexample2.com  http://3rdexample2.com  =LOOPUP for "1stexample" should return http://1stexample2.com
```

Any way to archive this with an Excel functions (VLOOKUP, HLOOKUP, INDEX, MATCH, etc)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `MATCH()` and `INDEX()`:

[image: Worksheet ScreenShot]

Enter this formula in `E2` and ctrl-enter/copy-paste/fill-down into the rest of the column:

```dart
=INDEX(A2:C2,MATCH("*"&D2&"*",A2:C2,0))
```

**Explanation:**

If the third argument of `MATCH()` is a `0` (exact match), then the find string can use wildcards. `*` means zero or more characters, so `MATCH("*1stexample*",…,0)` means match the first string containing the phrase `1stexample`.

Comment: @2by You're welcome. I just added an explanation if you need one.